# Why django does not validate email in CustomUser model?

Tags: django, django-models

I had the following custom user model:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

I was under the impression that I would at least get some errors if I tried to create a `CustomUser` with an invalid email. However, I have the following line it my unit tests:

```py
CustomUser.objects.create_user(email='dave') # creates user!
```

Shouldn't the above make django throw an error, since `'dave'` is clearly not an email? I know I can write a validator, but shouldn't there be already no need to do so?

Here's the `UserManager`:

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

**Update:** `CustomUser(email='dave').clean_fields()`, however, will throw the following error as expected: (but I am still curious what's up with my original question)

> ValidationError: {'password': ['This field cannot be blank.'], 'email': ['Enter a valid email address.']}

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps use [`EmailUserCreationForm`](https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user/issues/40) for complete validation

Answer (score 1):

Django does not run validators automatically outside of `ModelForm`'s.

So when you do this:

```py
CustomUser.objects.create_user(email='dave') # creates user!
```

The [`EmailField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#emailfield)'s validators (i.e. [`EmailValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.EmailValidator)) will not be run. An error will only be thrown if the *database* has an issue with the value you are trying to assign. In this case it won't, because under the hood an `EmailField` is identical to a `CharField` and you're passing it a string (`'dave'`).

[How validators are run (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run):

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm), it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.

I can understand the confusion. Your intuition is telling you that something defined in the models will be enforced by the ORM regardless of how it's represented in the database. The reality is that a lot of the Model field options are only used in forms (`blank`, `choices`, `editable`, `help_text` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

From the source, the class `AbstractUser` doesn't define a validator for the `email`field, but one for username.

So if you want a validation from the model's field, you have to do it yourself.
(and overwritte the username if you want to change it)